# Search and update a string in a text file in JAVA

Tags: java, file

I have two text files namely - item.txt (file 1) and temp.txt (file 2). My goal is to search for a name in the file 1 and if found then replace it with a different name and write the updated line to file 2. Also, I have a method that checks for the lines for the string I searched in file 1. The lines that do not contain that string will be added to file 2.

So, here is where I'm stuck. Everything works fine except the part where I want to delete file 1 and rename file 2 by file 1 (i.e item.txt). Can someone please help me with any correction? I am still a beginner in Java, so my code might not be the best looking code as one might expect but this is what I tried so far. Thanks
**The problem is when i compile the code the updated data is written to file2 and file1 which was supposed to get deleted doesn't delete. So, what could be the problem?**

```
package project4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kitkat {

    PrintWriter out,in;
    Scanner in;
    Scanner temp;
    File file1 = new File("item.txt");
    File file2 = new File("temp.txt");

    public void write() throws FileNotFoundException {
        out = new PrintWriter(file1);

        out.println("User1"+ "\t"+"639755"+"\t"+"400");
        out.println("User2"+ "\t"+"639725"+"\t"+"800");
        out.close();        
    }

    public void nfile() throws IOException {
        n = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file2,true));
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String replacement = "User3";
    String search;
    String total;

    public void search() {
        System.out.println("Enter your search name");
        search = input.nextLine();
        total = search; 
    }

    public void lolipop() throws IOException {
        in = new Scanner(file1);

        search();
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            String a,b,c;
            a = in.next();
            b = in.next();
            c = in.next();

            if(a.contains(search)) {
                System.out.println("Your match is found"+search);
                a = replacement;
                System.out.println(a+b+c);
                n.file();
                n.println(a+"\t"+b+"\t"+c);

                n.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void jellybeans() throws IOException {
        temp = new Scanner(file1);
        while(temp.hasNext()) {
            String p,q,r;
            p = temp.next();
            q = temp.next();
            r = temp.next();
            if(!(p.contains(total))) {
                System.out.println(p+q+r);
                n.file();
                n.println(p+"\t"+q+"\t"+r);
                n.close();
                renamefile();
            }
        }
    }

   public void renamefile() {
       file1.delete();
       file2.renameTo(file1);
   }    
}


package project4;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class tuna {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        kitkat kt = new kitkat();
        kt.lolipop();
        kt.jellybeans();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the rename? Do you get an error message? On which platform (operating system) do your run your code?

Comment: @siegi:- The problem is when i compile the code the updated data is written to file2 and file1 which was supposed to get deleted doesn't delete. I can see both the files(file1 and file2 ).So, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
public void renamefile() {
       String file1Path = file1.getAbsolutePath();
       file1.delete();
       file2.renameTo(new File(file1Path));
   }
```

Comment: :- Tried it but still doesnt work.The problem is when i compile the code the updated data is written to file2 and file1 which was supposed to get deleted doesn't delete. I can see both the files(file1 and file2 ).So, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc of [`File.renameTo(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-) the behavior of this method is platform dependent. If the rename does not succeed it simply returns `false` without throwing an exception. So I guess this would be the case here.

You can try the newer (since Java 7) [`Files.move(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-). This method is platform independent and has propper error handling, throwing exceptions with a problem description.